# Error while formating date with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date, formatting

I have a function that takes in a date and formats it. It works for time such as "10.33" and "9.33",

but for "10.09" it *wrongly shows "10.9"* instead, and the *"0" disappears.* Can anyone see the error in the function? I might have gone blind..

```
public static formatDate(date: Date): string {
        const year: string = date.getFullYear().toString();
        const month: string = date.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        const day: string = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate().toString();

        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try changing `date.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" +` to `date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" +`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.padStart`

```js
/*
public static formatDate(date: Date): string {
    const year: string = date.getFullYear().toString();
    const month: string = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    const day: string = date.getDate().toString();

  return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, 0)}-${day.padStart(2, 0)}`;
}
*/

const formatDate = date => {
const year = date.getFullYear().toString();
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    const day = date.getDate().toString();

  return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, 0)}-${day.padStart(2, 0)}`;
}


console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

I always prefer `momentjs` since every application has lots of things to with date manipulation, formating etc. but it depends on your project.

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems it does not work with Typescript? Type error at "${month.padStart(2, 0)}"   - ("Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'")

Comment: use `'0'` to match the type requirements